# Dynamically re-import Sass partials after amending variables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am working on a project utilizing Twitter Bootstrap pre-compiled with Sass.

Each time I override a variable, I have to re-import the `_bootstrap.sass` file to my project main stylesheet for the override to take effect.

Do you know of the way to make this process automatic so that, each time I amend a variable, it takes effect immediately?

To clarify further, this is my directory structure:

```
/project
  /custom-sass
    /boot.scss -> This is where _bootstrap.scss is imported
    /glob.scss
  /dev
    /bootstrap-sass
      /bootstrap
        /mixins
        /partial1.scss
        /partial2.scss
        /etc..
      /_bootstrap.scss -> This is the main Bootstrap Sass file that imports all partials.
```

When I override a variable directly in _variables.scss, and then re-import `_bootstrap.scss` with this directive: `@import '../dev/bootstrap-sass/_bootstrap.scss` in my boot.scss, the styles get updated.

However, I do not want to override variables directly in `_variables.scss`. Moreover, I do not want to be forced to re-import `_bootstrap.scss` in my main style sheet each time I make a change.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  You recognize that the variables must be set *before* you use them.  So define them before you use them?  Modifying _variables.scss has never been a requirement, it's there as a convenience for you.

Comment: Yes, but even if I define a variable before I use it, I still have to re-import the main `_bootstrap.scss` usually by hitting a space or other key so that I can re-save the main stylesheet that imports `_bootstrap.scss`. Only then it gets reimported and styles are re-applied to the document. I hope that it is clearer what the problem is.

Comment: So the actual problem is that your Sass file(s) is not being recompiled when you make changes?

Comment: I believe the reason is that once styles are applied to the document, you have to re-import (e.g. `_bootstrap.scss`) for the styles to be readded to the document. Let's say I applied `$margin: 10px` to the document. Later, I decide to amend `$margin` to `20px`. For the changes to take effect, I have to rewrite the directive `@import bootstrap-sass/bootstrap`and save the file again. This is really cumbersome. Let me add that `$margin` is imported to the main `_bootstrap.sass`. My main styles file imports only `_bootstrap.scss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no language that will do what you're suggesting.  If you specify `$margin: 10px` and then run some code that uses that variable, you can't change it to `20px` and expect it to retroactively change the results of code that's already been run.

If you want `$margin: 20px`, then you specify it that way before you run the procedures (mixins, imports, etc.) that depends on it.  In other words, move your Bootstrap imports so that they are *after* you set your variables.

Comment: Yes, I agree in principle. However, I believe it is possible to set variable listeners in e.g. JavaScript or at least some of its frameworks. As for the problem I was trying to explain - I'm using Grunt to run certain tasks in my project. Mayby Grunt can help out with dynamic variable re-assignement?

Comment: Callbacks won't go back in time and change the results of the procedures that have *already been processed*.