# Updating a SASS variable within an extended class

Tags: sass

Is there a way to update a SASS variable within an extended class? For example I have this currently:

```
  .menu-highlight-1 {
    $child: 1;
    a {
        &:nth-child(#{$child})  {
          color: red !important;
      }
    }
  }
```

And I want to update the `$child` variable to the next element, so in my attempt I've extended the `.menu-highlight-1` class and then made a change to the `$child` variable. However all this does is highlight the same item from the extended class.

```
  .menu-highlight-2 {
    @extend .menu-highlight-1;
    $child: 2;
  }
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081313/cannot-get-color-functions-to-work-using-a-sass-map and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543270/dynamically-re-import-sass-partials-after-amending-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem using a SASS mixin. Thanks to @cimmanon and this thread: [Updating variables created by lighten/darken functions by modifying the original base color afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081313/cannot-get-color-functions-to-work-using-a-sass-map)

```
@mixin _menuHighlight($child) {
  a {
      &:nth-child(#{$child})  {
      color: red !important;
    }
  }
}

  .menu-highlight-1 {
    @include _menuHighlight(1);
  }

  .menu-highlight-2 {
    @include _menuHighlight(2);
  }
```